# Upgrade from WSUS 2.0 to 3.0?

Tags: windows-server-2003, wsus

Is there a reason to upgrade from Windows Server Update Services (WSUS) 2.0 to 3.0?

I have a Windows 2003 Small Business Server currently running WSUS 2.0 serving 7 Windows XP client machines.

Is it worth it to upgrade? What are the benefits? Does it require re-configuring all the client machines?

Or should I just "leave well enough alone?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would upgrade immediately to WSUS 3.0 SP1.  Microsoft has stopped supporting WSUS 2.0 SP1 as of April 30 according to [the product page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/wsus/bb466202.aspx), which may mean they may stop allowing it to pull updates from Microsoft Update (which may have already occurred).

The client machines may see an update to their Automatic Updates client, but they shouldn't require reconfiguration.

Comment: Now THAT is a good argument to upgrade. You've convinced me - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

3.0 has a nicer and much more responsive management console (Moves from web console to a management console extension).  Certainly worth the upgrade.

Comment: I agree, it is more responsive, and I had no problems (your mileage may vary ;)

Comment: Is that the only benefit though? That it has a nicer management console?

Comment: Well, its also the only supported version. It's not a minor management enhancement either, the old one used to be extremely laggy and often hung when I was using it. I've not had any problems with the new one, I certainly consider it a major upgrade. There may be backend changes, I've not really looked.  It doesnt require a reconfiguration of client machines, I can't really see any reason not to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Summary from the [Microsoft TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc708601(WS.10).aspx):

- Get e-mail messages about new updates
- Cleanup (remove old information easily)
- Faster synchronization

**New Administration Console**

- Advanced filtering
- New columns allowing you to sort updates according to MSRC number, MSRC severity, KB article, and installation status
- Column selection, sorting, and reordering
- Shortcut menus, allowing you to right-click and choose an action
- Reporting integrated with update views
- Custom views